WinMerge filter to compare files and exclude specific folder
I'm trying to create a filter to compare only .cpp and .h files but it shouldn't compare folders which name .vshistory.
This is what i got:
## This is a directory/file filter template for WinMerge
name: C++ Files
desc: Filter for C++ source and header files

## This is an exclusive filter
## (it lets through only matching files)
def: exclude

f: \.(cpp|h)$  ## To compare only .cpp and .h files
d: \\(?<!\.vshistory)

Its comparing only .cpp and .h files but its not ignoring the .vshistory folder, what's wrong?
https://i.imgur.com/QmENUAx.png

Do you want to match \ but not preceded by .vshistory ? \\(?<!\.vshistory\\)

Please try this one:
## This is a directory/file filter template for WinMerge
name: C++ Files
desc: Filter for C++ source and header files

## This is an exclusive filter
## (it lets through only matching files)
def: exclude

f: \.(cpp|h)$  ## To compare only .cpp and .h files
d: ^(?:(?!\.vshistory).)*$  ## Ignore the .vshistory directory


Thank you it worked, suppose i need to add another folder named "test" is this correct? ^(?:(?!(\.vshistory|test)).)*$

^(?:(?!.vshistory)(?!\test).)*$
